# Set Builder Notation with quantifier

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The standard set builder notation is presented in many books as:

$\{x:P(x)$}

But this seems to make more sense:

$\{\forall x:P(x)$}

I've never seen it with a $\forall$ quantifier in front of the object $x$ though. I just want to make sure this is correct.

Comment: It doesn't make more sense. The things on the left of the colon/vertical line are not a statement or a formula, but rather, a list. Do you write $\{1\}$ or $\{\forall 1\}$?

Comment: The symbol $\forall$ means “**for** all”, which makes exactly zero sense in the set builder scenario. It's the set *of* all $x$ for which $P(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A = \{x | P(x)\}$ simply declares that 'the set A is the set of all x, such that x satisfies the predicate P'.  It is a shorthand way of writing the equivalent statement in logic, being $\forall x(x \in A \leftrightarrow P(x))$